# hesitant as to whether to preceed with dual boot installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have a msi-gaming laptop with Windows 10 installed.

I wanted to install Ubuntu 16.04 as dual-boot alongside my current windows 10. There were a few obstacles:

1. there was a blank-purple screen: to solve it I set `nomodeset` and it went on...
2. there was no option "install Ubuntu alongside windows 10", I chose "something else" following the suggestions from this site...
3. it directed me to partition the disks. There was no **"windows loader"** in the box, but only some values such as:

   ```
    free space 1 MB;
    /dev/sda1/ntfs with the 528345 MB 87947 MB used;
    /dev/sda2/ntfs with the 429495 MB 150 MB used;
    free space 1 MB;
    /dev/sda3 with the 21474 MB unknown;
    free space 0 MB;
    /dev/sda4 ntfs with the 20885 20100 MB used;
    free space 0 MB.
   ```

   Before all I had already partitioned two disk spaces (30GB and 400GB) in Windows using disk partitioning...
4. Then I deleted these two:

   - /dev/sda4 ntfs with the 20885 20100 MB used 
     and
   - /dev/sda3 with the 21474 MB unknown; to free some space for SWAP, root and boot and home (Mount point).

   I assigned appropriate sizes for respective mount points, again followed advice from Ask Ubuntu here. They are as follows:

   ```
   /dev/sda3 swap 2047 MB unknown;
   /dev/sda4 ext4 /home 10240 MB unknown;
   /dev/sda5 ext4 / 20479 MB unknown;
   /dev/sda6 biosgrub 5 MB  unknown;
   ```

[image]

And finally, the most dangerous part for me:

After clicking **install now** button, there is a window asking **Write the changes to disks?**

**Question**:

Will I lose my windows system data and system itself if I click continue? If yes, what are the other ways to safely install Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot looks OK. You can proceed. The Windows partitions should not be affected. You chose not to format them.

Comment: Thank you, I clicked the button. :) I am curious about when I chose not to format them!

Comment: You did not choose to format them, that is closer to the truth. ;-) You see the "Format?" column?

Comment: hi, I am having a big trouble booting to Ubuntu 16.04. My boot menu only shows Windows, not Ubuntu.
I tried to use Boot repair disk as suggested on the web.
to run this it requires Internet connection, I do have Internet in windows, boot repair is not detecting any network connections.
What should I do know?

Comment: This is a grub issue. You can search for an existing answer, or ask a new question.